# How can i add floating button in constraint layout

Tags: java, android

the error said

"Resource Errors
This project contains resource errors, so aapt did not succeed, which can cause rendering failures. Fix resource problems first."

How can I add floating action button in constraint layout

here is my code

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_wishlist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_heart"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/cardview_dark_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.972"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Try This!**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/abc_vector_test" />
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks sir got it. I really apricate your help <3 @Emon Hossain Munna